# Insert data from one DB into another on a different server - servers not linked

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am trying to copy some selected data from one DB, set on a server that is expiring on Jan 1st, into another so that I can preserve it.
The second DB is on a different server, different host etc - I no longer have access to the first one, but only know the various locations of the items I require.

I have done a few searches about how to do this, but most of the times I come up with the requirements to link servers - which given my lack of access to the original one, is not an option.

I have coded the following, although whenever I run the script (which I only need once and on demand) I get a gateway timeout.

```
$link = mysql_connect('XXXXaddressXXXX', 'XXXXuserXXXX', 'XXXXXXpwXXXXX');  //edited out the access details for security
$row = mysql_select_db('sfi_db', $link);


$query = "SELECT t.entry_id, t.title, t.year, t.month, t.day, d.field_id_1, d.field_id_2, d.field_id_3 FROM sfi_db.exp_channel_titles t LEFT JOIN sfi_db.exp_channel_data d ON t.entry_id = d.entry_id WHERE d.field_id_5='Latest-Updates'";
$results=mysql_query($query); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($results)){
    $id=$row[0];
    $title = $row[1];
    $year = $row[2];
    $month = $row[3];
    $day = $row[4];
    $summary = $row[5];
    $body = $row[6];
    $image = $row[7];

    $dBIP='XXXAddressOfSecondServerXXXX';
    $dBADN='XXXXUserofSecondServerXXXX';
    $dBPWD='XXXXPWofSecondServer';
    $dBDBS="XXXXDBnameXXXX";

    // Connection
    $CONNECTW=mysql_connect($dBIP,$dBADN,$dBPWD);
    $row=mysql_select_db($dBDBS, $CONNECTW);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $dBIP.$dBDBS.newsimport (id,title,year,month,day,summary,body,image_url) VALUES ('$id','$title','$year','$month','$day','$summary','$body','$image')",$CONNECTW);


    $link = mysql_connect('XXXXaddressXXXX', 'XXXXuserXXXX', 'XXXXXXpwXXXXX');
    $row = mysql_select_db('sfi_db', $link);
    }
```

The final connection is to re-connect to the first DB as the script is meant to run for each item in the original first query.

Any help to find out what I am doing wrong would be precious! Thank you.

/// EDITED FOLLOWING THE FIRST REPLIES

I have now edited the code but still get the 504 gateway error. The new code reads as follows:

```
// Connection 1
$link = mysql_connect('XXXXaddressXXXX', 'XXXXuserXXXX', 'XXXXXXpwXXXXX');  //edited out the access details for security
$row = mysql_select_db('sfi_db', $link);

    $dBIP='XXXAddressOfSecondServerXXXX';
    $dBADN='XXXXUserofSecondServerXXXX';
    $dBPWD='XXXXPWofSecondServer';
    $dBDBS="XXXXDBnameXXXX";

// Connection 2
$CONNECTW=mysql_connect($dBIP,$dBADN,$dBPWD);
$row=mysql_select_db($dBDBS, $CONNECTW);


$query = "SELECT t.entry_id, t.title, t.year, t.month, t.day, d.field_id_1, d.field_id_2, d.field_id_3 FROM sfi_db.exp_channel_titles t LEFT JOIN sfi_db.exp_channel_data d ON t.entry_id = d.entry_id WHERE d.field_id_5='Latest-Updates'";
$results=mysql_query($query); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($results)){
    $id=$row[0];
    $title = $row[1];
    $year = $row[2];
    $month = $row[3];
    $day = $row[4];
    $summary = $row[5];
    $body = $row[6];
    $image = $row[7];


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $dBIP.$dBDBS.newsimport (id,title,year,month,day,summary,body,image_url) VALUES ('$id','$title','$year','$month','$day','$summary','$body','$image')",$CONNECTW);

    }
```

Comment: Don't open a new connection to the second server each time through the loop.

Comment: You can export database from other server and import in new server database.

Comment: I'm little bit lost here, you said that you no longer have access to the first one, how do you want to connect to it to get the data?

Comment: You don't need to reconnect to the first DB. The connection stays open.

Comment: You have total 3 mysql_connect() in your code. one outside the loop and 2 inside the loop.Remove unnecessary mysql connect. Also just move the mysql_connect() outside the loop.

Comment: Thank you to all who replied! I will try and remove the surplus connections.
@JorgeCampos - I can still connect to it, what I don't have access is a phpmyadmin/other utility to access the DB via an interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Connection 1
$link = mysql_connect('XXXXaddressXXXX', 'XXXXuserXXXX', 'XXXXXXpwXXXXX');  //edited out the access details for security
mysql_select_db('sfi_db', $link) or die("Can't connect to first database");

// Connection 2
$dBIP='XXXAddressOfSecondServerXXXX';
$dBADN='XXXXUserofSecondServerXXXX';
$dBPWD='XXXXPWofSecondServer';
$dBDBS="XXXXDBnameXXXX";

$CONNECTW=mysql_connect($dBIP,$dBADN,$dBPWD);
mysql_select_db($dBDBS, $CONNECTW)  or die("Can't connect to second database");;


$query = "SELECT t.entry_id, t.title, t.year, t.month, t.day, d.field_id_1, d.field_id_2, d.field_id_3 FROM sfi_db.exp_channel_titles t LEFT JOIN sfi_db.exp_channel_data d ON t.entry_id = d.entry_id WHERE d.field_id_5='Latest-Updates'";
$results=mysql_query($query,$link); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_row($results)){
    $id=$row[0];
    $title = $row[1];
    $year = $row[2];
    $month = $row[3];
    $day = $row[4];
    $summary = $row[5];
    $body = $row[6];
    $image = $row[7];


    mysql_query("INSERT INTO $dBDBS.newsimport (id,title,year,month,day,summary,body,image_url) VALUES ('$id','$title','$year','$month','$day','$summary','$body','$image')",$CONNECTW);

    }
```

What has changed:

1. removed the `row=` after each connection in favor of a die if it can't connect.
2. Specify the connection in the first query with `$link`
3. Removed $dBIP from the Insert query as a.b.C sounds not a valid table name.

This should work, your 504 error could be because your script takes too long to execute and you hit the [timeout parameter](http://php.net/manual/fr/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time)

You may resolve this by calling [set_time_limit()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.set-time-limit.php) at the end of each loop or by changing the value into `php.ini`. think that your webserver (apache or other) has a timeout on GET request too.

Comment: Still getting some issues - if I edit out the connection to the second DB, and add a test dump after the first query, it appears to be working. Whenever I add the connection to the second db, it stalls. This is fairly odd as that connection is what I regularly use for second-db-only operations :S

Comment: What kind of test dump ? Do you still specify the correct link id in your query ?

Comment: I have limited the first SELECT query to a limit of 1 and, in my test, I have it dump the value of $id. If I remove the second connection, it'll succeed, but the moment I re-enable it, it'll stall (even though I set the time limit to more than 10 minutes).

Comment: I just noticed the $dBIP before the $dDBS in the insert query, looks like it's Hat mysql don't like.

Comment: Not really sure about that - it stalls even if I out comment the insert query.

Could the stalling be given by the fact that the connection to the second db, whose IP is $dBIP='sql.winwithsaharaforceindia.com', needs some extra parameter as that is the server onto which the script is not running?

Comment: It may stall at connect if something was wrong (firewall, etc), but would die in this case as the select db won't succeed... You may add echos  to see where the script hangs...

Comment: It appears the hanging happens here: $CONNECTW=mysql_connect($dBIP,$dBADN,$dBPWD);

Comment: Is your host server allowed to connect to mysql on this second one ? (firewalls problem ?)

Comment: I am trying to establish this - unfortunately, the company that developed and hosted the site left a while ago and didn't exactly leave me a user guide...

Comment: Could it be that the second server is just listening locally and not allowing remote connections ?

Comment: Not sure. If that was the case, would there be no way to do this at all?

Comment: If you can't connect remotely, not this way at least,  you may get a dump in file and transfert it to destination by other way (ft, ssh) and then load this dump file... Without more information on the architecture it's hard to tell

Comment: Thank you for all your feedback @tensibai - I will look into it. Much appreciated!